# Improvement of Von Neumann's measurement scheme

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, measurement-problem, foundations

I would like to know some  references on possible improvements of [Von Neumann's measurement scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#von_Neumann_measurement_scheme) beyond the use of POVMs.

Specifically, I am interested in the possibility of implementing a sort of post measurement state transformation generalizing the "collapse of wavefunction" which is built-in in the definition of the measurement procedure.

Furthermore, I would like to understand the following point: should we consider the measurement process as an "instantaneous interaction" (very much like operations in quantum information theory), or should we model it as a continuous dynamical evolution?

Comment: Hi, this site is not designed for opinion related question,  it's more around Q and A. If you want references, you might consider putting in the resources recommended tag

Comment: This post is discussed in the hbar chat room [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35279823#35279823).

Comment: think this could be somehow be meaningfully rephrased as not opinion based. anyway plz drop by [chat] & suggest you look into weak measurements/ newly emerging hydrodynamic fluid analogies. see also my blog re viral Veritasium video etc https://vzn1.wordpress.com/2016/11/07/veritasium-launches-soliton-dynamics-into-1m-viral-living-legend/

Comment: Hi Ilcapitano: It seems the [tag:specific-reference] tag does not apply cf. its [tag wiki](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-reference/info).

Comment: A measurement is just an interaction that copies information from one system to another, it's not instantaneous, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245. The vn measurement scheme is at best a rule of thumb for what you might see when doing a measurement, which is not real physics. Also, quantum information doesn't assume that operations happen instantaneously, just that each operation takes places in a finite time.

Comment: What does it mean to copy information? What is this information that is being copied? How do you model the interaction which is taking place?